# Обработать пустой ответ JSON

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rxjava

С сервера приходит ответ такого плана:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1197309,
        "building_id": 324505,
    },
    {
        "id": 1197309,
        "building_id": 324505,
    }
]
```

Но в некоторых ситуациях приходит просто пустой массив

```
[]
```

При этом запрос завершается `onSuccess`, но RV получается пустым.

вот так:

```
if (pojoList.size()==0 || pojoList.isEmpty() ){
    textError();
}
```

не прокатывает

Вопрос как обработать ответ что бы поймать и вывести сообщение что даных нет.

```
private void getTom(String start, String end) {
    String access_token = "access_token ";
    progressBarTrain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    disposable.add(
            rxConnector.getTom().getTom(start, time, access_token)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<List<Responce>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(@NonNull List<Responce> pojoList) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            generateDataList(pojoList);

                        /*так не ловится 
                        *if (pojoList.size()==0 || pojoList.isEmpty() ){
                         *   textError();
                        * }
                        * а надо поймать
                        */
                        Log.e(TAG, "onSuccess: " + pojoList.size());
                        cardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "onError: " + e.getMessage() + e.toString());
                            textError();
                        }
                    }));
}
```

Comment: `pojoList` не пустой ведь? А что в его первом элементе Responce?

Comment: В том то и дело, чт pojolist при некоторых датах в параметрах пустой, например выходной день

Comment: @Романыч, вы через дебагер можете проверить, что у вас в `pojolist`, когда там пусто? У вас, скорее всего size не будет пустым, так как в `List` есть `[ ]`, и по той же причине, `size ==1`. Но проверка на 1, это не правильно. Что у вас внутри pojolist? 2 элемента, если вернулось `{
        "id": 1197309,
        "building_id": 324505,
    },
    {
        "id": 1197309,
        "building_id": 324505,
    }` ?

Comment: `Log.e(TAG, "onSuccess: " + pojoList.size());` - а что выводит эта строка при пустом массиве? А лучше эта: `Log.e(TAG, "onSuccess: \n" + pojoList);` ?